# Google Static Maps Api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

i was using google maps api v1 and i could draw the map to a canvas and save it and now im using google maps api v2 because i got my debug key before march 13th and just this weekend was ready to sign and couldnt because i didnt know it was going to be discontinued, so, the questions i have are:

```
1: is static maps api the correct way to do what i was doing in google maps 
api v1 draw the mapView to a canvas and compress the bitmap.

2: if it is does 25000 free requests pertain to me the developer or
 each individual user of the app that i am making?
```

thank you for your time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you confused Google Maps API v2 (also depracated) with Google Maps **Android** API v2.

The new API is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

The Android API v2 has no such limits.

Comment: your right, i cannot get a release key these days for using maps v1 on android though can i, and to get an actual bitmap from the maps view and compress as png is that impossible?

Comment: No, you can't get a new key for Android API v1. I'm not sure about getting bitmap from API v2 view. Maybe ask another question about it?

Comment: thanks for your time, i did put another question out earlier, thanks again, would you like the point up or you need unsung hero badge or how would you like, this was usefull to me i usually upvote usefull ones

Comment: Don't really care about these badges. I like solving problems.

Comment: thats cool, thanks for the input i fixed the whole problem, if i can ask one more, for the google static maps it says 25000 free maps then you have to pay, is that the developer has to pay, and its every map or map tile downloaded? do you know about that, its a million things

Comment: Never used static maps. If you send API key with request, I'd guess it is per key, if not - per IP.